# What does 'default' really mean for UITextInputTrait constants

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I'm trying to explain to someone there's 3 options for `UITextAutocorrectionType`, yes, no, and default.  They asked me what `default` meant.  I have no idea.  [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextautocorrectiontype) is not very helpful.  Does anyone have further insight?

> case `default`
>
> Specifies an appropriate autocorrection behavior for the current script system.

Just as elusive are defaults for `UITextSpellCheckingType` and `UIKeyboardType`

Are these defaults set by the user on their own phone/system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default` says to use whatever value is set in the iOS Settings app under General -> Keyboard. If the "Auto-correction" setting is enabled and the `UITextAutocorrectionType` is set to `default` then the auto correct will be used. If the "Auto-correction" setting is disabled then the auto correct won't be used.

`no` explicitly says not to do any autocorrection regardless of the "Auto-correction" setting.

`yes` explicitly says to do autocorrect regardless of the "Auto-correction" setting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out exactly where in settings I could confirm that.